# pull out some div tags and put into the json or xml file format with c#

Tags: c#, html, css, xml, json

I'd like to pull out some div tags and their inside tags from a html web page url and convert those tags into XML or JSON file format. I am looking for a solution(theoretically) for doing that. could anyone please provide me with any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS2005 and above, this might help you. Use the Spire.doc tool which go well with Visual studio.

Spire.Doc is an MS Word component which enables user to perform a wide range of Word document processing tasks directly, such as generate, read, write and modify Word document for .NET and Silverlight.

Spire.Doc presents an easy solution to convert HTML to XML. We just need create a project in visual studio and use the simple 3 lines of  code below. Now, copy the code below into your project to convert files from HTML to XML.

[C#]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Spire.Doc;

namespace Xml2Pdf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.LoadFromFile("sample.html", FileFormat.Html);
            doc.SaveToFile("test.xml", FileFormat.Xml);
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: If this works, Vote this answer so that it will be helpful to others)

Regards,

Mani

Comment: instead of static html"sample.html", i suggest you to refer the page by getting url or pass the entire query string by which you can make it work. Worth a try. tnx.

Comment: Thank you.I tested. firstly it does not work with URL, secondly even does not work with html text file. I think it works for another purposes like manipulate word format file.

Answer (score 0):

**WebClient** class provides common methods for sending / receiving data from any local, intranet, or Internet resource identified by a URI.

The WebClient class uses the **WebRequest** class to provide access to resources. WebClient instances can access data with any WebRequest.

**there are three steps you can do with this object:**

1. get a page HTML/Anchor Tag's/ Div Content from URL or from those web pages
2. export the collection to JSON or XML
3. And later play with JSON or XML Data :p

The above mentioned is just the theoritical stuff
and if you really wanna try it practically [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/488939/Get-page-HTML-from-URL-using-WebClient-Strip-HTML) might help you to get the list of HTML Tags from page